# How to limit file size for multipart/form-data upload to Servant server?

Tags: haskell, file-upload, servant

The documentation at [hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-multipart](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-multipart-0.12.1/docs/Servant-Multipart.html) says about the main combinator `type MultipartForm tag a` following:

> Note that the behavior of this combinator is configurable, by using `serveWith` from servant-server instead of `serve`, which takes an additional `Context` argument. It simply is an heterogeneous list where you can for example store a value of type `MultipartOptions` that has the configuration that you want, which would then get picked up by servant-multipart.

And later:

> `data MultipartOptions tag` 
> Global options for configuring how the server should handle multipart data. 
> `generalOptions` lets you specify mostly multipart parsing related options, such as the maximum file size …

However, I don't understand how to correctly call the mentioned `serveWithContext`:

```hs
serveWithContext 
  :: (HasServer api context, ServerContext context) 
  => Proxy api 
  -> Context context 
  -> Server api  
  -> Application
```

Searching for its usage on GitHub also didn't enlighten me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Following code does the job:

```hs
import Prelude (($))
import Servant
  ( Application, Proxy(Proxy)
  , Context(EmptyContext, (:.)), serveWithContext
  )
import Servant.Multipart
  ( MultipartOptions(generalOptions)
  , defaultMultipartOptions, Mem
  )
import Network.Wai.Parse
  ( defaultParseRequestBodyOptions, setMaxRequestFileSize )

app :: Application
app =
  let
    size10MB = 10000000
    multipartOpts = (defaultMultipartOptions (Proxy :: Proxy Mem))
      { generalOptions =
          setMaxRequestFileSize size10MB
          defaultParseRequestBodyOptions
      }
    context = multipartOpts :. EmptyContext
  in
    serveWithContext appApi context appSserver
```

Make sure to use the correct `MultipartData` tag for the Proxy type (`Mem` or `Tmp`). Documentation: [hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-multipart](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-multipart-0.12.1/docs/Servant-Multipart.html#t:MultipartData)

You can check out [hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-3.1.8/docs/Network-Wai-Parse.html) for all available config changes.